# GCP generativelanguage.googleapis.com not able to enable

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai, generative

I am trying to use this api to call the text-bison model. I get the  error below. And when I go to api console, I do not see any option to enable it.

> google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403 Generative Language
> API has not been used in project 969406701988 before or it is
> disabled. Enable it by visiting
> https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/generativelanguage.googleapis.com/overview?project=969406701988
> then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for
> the action to propagate to our systems and retry.

```
[links {
  description: "Google developers console API activation"
  url: "https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/generativelanguage.googleapis.com/overview?project=969406701988"
}
, reason: "SERVICE_DISABLED"
domain: "googleapis.com"
metadata {
  key: "service"
  value: "generativelanguage.googleapis.com"
}
metadata {
  key: "consumer"
  value: "projects/969406701988"
}
]
```

Comment: Did you followed the provided link? If so, what the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the service `generativelanguage.googleapis.com` is in private beta at this time, you have to join a waitlist at https://cloud.google.com/ai/generative-ai

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Google AI website](https://cloud.google.com/ai/generative-ai), this is GA now yet I still receive "SERVICE_DISABLED".

Comment: I am able to use it